# How do I Install Drupal Locally

Tags: installation, theming

I have a html doc and css for a site that I do not currently have live. I want to use Drupal for the site but have a question about testing when changing the html/css into something compatible with Drupal: How do I check my progress to make sure things are working?

With an HTML doc, all I have to do is click the doc and it opens up in my browser. How do I test with Drupal in that way?

What steps do I take to install Drupal locally? I am running Windows, so do I use WAMP? I am a total noob, any help would be more than awesome.

Comment: there are two questions here: how to install Drupal on Windows (for newbies) and how to turn your HTML+CSS templates into a Drupal Theme.  
Please, open up another question for turning HTML+CSS into Theme.

Comment: The question is about testing my site locally so that I can view my progress in converting HTML + CSS to Drupal. I already have a guide on that, just describing why I want to install it locally. Only one question here, installing it locally.

Comment: I strongly suggest using a package such as XAMPP or WAMP. That way you get a prepackaged set of applications with compatible versions guaranteed to work together. Plus it's easier than assembling it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to install Drupal locally to test the theme progress. There is a nice guide at http://drupal.org/node/307956, I hope it works for you. Please post back if you need more guidance. It is the easier way I know to get started with Drupal on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would install [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and run your local install from there. As another answer suggests, there is a simple guide (http://drupal.org/node/307956).

Converting html/css into a theme could be a lot of work for your first few tries. You'll need to learn a lot about them theme system and drupal in general. Lullabot has a good [walk-through video](http://store.lullabot.com/products/theming-basics-advanced-bundle) available, also likely on their site Drupalize.me. This costs money, but would definitely minimize the time you spend doing your conversion. Specifcally, you'll get to see how they test their progress on a local server.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, having used XAMPP and WAMP, if I wanted a quick and easy local install of Drupal, I would use [Acquia Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop) instead. Their tagline "Drupal made simple" says it all, really.

You can download it from [here](http://www.acquia.com/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely consider what EddieN120 and mtro suggest.

I have been trying to download drupal sites from our clients and use them in Microsoft IIS, and have run into MANY issues. More IIS issues than Drupal. Part of the reason that I have not adapted the Acquia Dev or just a XAMMP set up is because the workstation which I use is filled with different versions of PHP.

Based on previous experience, Acquia Drupal is the easiest way to set up a local test site. It pretty much packages XAMMP/WAMMP along with other common tools.

Answer (score -2):

Check this out: https://github.com/cyberswat/drupal-lamp  It is pretty dang easy to install.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.